# To-Do List Python function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I’m trying to write a function that manages a to-do list per day by using nested lists (with a depth of 2). I’m working from a file that has defined a list of tasks. The format for one task would look like this:

```
'email', 9, 15, 2, 0, 70, 'Answer all the emails received today.'
```

the format of each task is:

- Name of the task.
- Date of the task: month (an integer between 1 and 12).
- Date of the task: day (an integer between 1 and 31).
- Start time of the task: hour (in a 24-hour format, hence an int between 1 and 24), e.g., for 9:15 AM, this entry is 9. If the start time is 11:45 PM, this entry is 23.
- Start time of the task: minute (an int between 0 and 59).
- Length of the task (in minutes): A task length of 2 hours and 20 minutes is 140 minutes.
- General description of the task.

My function has to take in a date in the form [10,1] (denotes October 1) and print out all the the tasks for that day ordered based on their start times. It should look like this:

```
These are your tasks for Oct. 1
Task Name: coffee
        Start time:  8:25 AM
        End time:    8:30 AM
        Description: making coffee

Task Name: lunch
        Start time: 12:00 PM
        End time:   12:30 PM
        Description: Lunch time
```

How can I approach this? I have defined functions for the month and the day, but I’m trying to first write a function that compares the dates and then the tasks depending on which ones come first. Please let me know if you can help.

```
def print_tasks(tasks, date_list):
    """Print all the tasks for the given date from the given list of tasks.

    Arguments:
    tasks--A nested list, where each inner list represents the information on
    a single task.
    date_list--a list of two integers representing the month and day for which
    the tasks should be printed. For example, [10, 1] represents Oct. 10th
    (month=10, day=1).
    """
    for task in tasks:
        if task[1] == date[0] and task[2] == date[1]:
            if task[3] > 12:
                start_time = ' PM'
                task[3] -= 12
            else:
                start_time = ' AM'
            if task[3] > 12:
                end_time = ' PM'
                task[3] -= 12
            else: end_time = ' AM'
            print 'Task Name:', task[0]
            print 'Start time:', task[3], ':', task[4]
            print 'End time:'

    # Please complete me. Define several other functions and call them here
    # to complete me.


def main():
    """The main function (please don't remove). However, please feel free to
    change the second argument passed to print_tasks here to test your
    print_tasks function with different inputs.
    """
    # The variable tasks is the nested list storing the tasks.
    return None
```

## Updated Code:

```
tasks = [
  ['email', 9, 15, 2, 0, 70, 'Answer all the emails received today.'],
  ['coffee', 10, 1, 8, 25, 5, 'making coffee'],
  ['meeting', 3, 5, 12, 0, 80, 'group meeting'],
  ['sleep', 12, 8, 3, 20, 280, 'getting some sleep'],
  ['meeting', 10, 1, 17, 0, 60, 'group meeting'],
  ['laundry', 3, 5, 21, 0, 40, 'do laundry'],
  ['office hours', 10, 1, 14, 0, 120, 'Office hours for Biology II'],
  ['class', 3, 5, 15, 0, 50, 'CS1 class'],
  ['laundry', 11, 5, 13, 0, 80, 'Laundry'],
  ['laundry', 10, 1, 19, 45, 40, 'Do laundry'],
  ['lunch', 10, 1, 12, 0, 30, 'Lunch time'],
  ['class', 3, 5, 10, 0, 50, 'Philosophy class'],
  ['break', 2, 1, 11, 0, 45, 'quick break before lunch.'],
  ['exam prep', 11, 13, 10, 0, 600, 'study for the exam.']]


def make_date_from_tasks(tasks):
  dates = []
  for task in tasks:
    dates.append([task[1], task[2]])
  return dates

dates = make_date_from_tasks(tasks)

def task_month(number):
    if number == 1:
        return 'January'
    if number == 2:
        return 'February'
    elif number == 3:
        return 'March'
    elif number == 4:
        return 'April'
    elif number == 5:
        return 'May'
    elif number == 6:
        return 'June'
    elif number == 7:
        return 'July'
    elif number == 8:
        return 'August'
    elif number == 9:
        return 'September'
    elif number == 10:
        return 'October'
    elif number == 11:
        return 'November'
    else:
        return 'December'

def print_tasks(tasks, date_list):
    for task in tasks:
      if task[1] == date[0] and task[2] == date[1]:
        if task[3] > 12:
          start_time = ' PM'
          task[3] -= 12
        else:
          start_time = ' AM'
        if task[3] > 12:
          end_time = ' PM'
          task[3] -= 12
        else:
          end_time = ' AM'
        print statements (I’m confused as to what to write here to format it correctly)

for date in dates:
  print_tasks(tasks, date)
```

Comment: Any code you've written so far?

Comment: I have bits. I’m trying to extract the starting time of each event (and store these times in a list), then get the indices that sort that list (by using the list_sort function, a function I already defined). Ideally, these indices would tell me what is the right order for these starting times (and their corresponding tasks) to get them ordered. The task will be sorted based on their start times.

Comment: I've improved formatting (to make it understandable) and added tag "python" (for larger audience)

Comment: Show your code attempts here. People are more likely to help when they  see your effort.

Comment: Can I ask why you're not using dates to represent dates? A comparison of dates is considerably easier and will also handle validation.

Comment: Is this a fixed format or can we propose something new?

Comment: I think it’s a fixed format. I’m a beginner and this is part 2 of a problem set. Basically, I can only use what we’ve learned: lists, nested loops, comparing length of items in a list, indexing, etc.

Comment: I’m not sure about the dates, but I think I’me expected to input a number [10,1] and have all the corresponding tasks show up.

Answer (score 1):

I made a small example of how I would approach this...

Assume we have an array with data (could be stored in a external file or database):

```
jsonarray = [
    {
    'name':'email',
    'datetime':"2017-09-15 04:00:00",
    'length':70,
    'description':'Answer all the emails received today.'
    },
    {
    'name':'email',
    'datetime':"2017-09-16 08:00:00",
    'length':70,
    'description':'Answer all the emails received today.'
    },
    {
    'name':'email',
    'datetime':"2017-09-15 03:00:00",
    'length':70,
    'description':'Answer all the emails received today.'
    }
]
```

We could then read the data and create a function that returns a formatted string that we can print based on a date:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(jsonarray)
df.datetime = pd.to_datetime(df.datetime)

printformat = """
Task Name: {}
Start time: {}
End time: {}
Description: {}
"""

def print_tasks(maskby):
    mask = df[df['datetime'].dt.date.astype(str) == maskby].sort_values(by='datetime')
    s = ['These are your tasks for {}:\n'.format(maskby)]
    for ind,row in mask.iterrows():
        name = row["name"]
        stime = row["datetime"].strftime("%H:%M")
        etime = (row["datetime"] + datetime.timedelta(minutes=row["length"])).strftime("%H:%M")
        desc = row["description"]
        s.append(printformat.format(name,stime,etime,desc))
    return ''.join(s)

print(print_tasks("2017-09-15"))
```

Output:

```
These are your tasks for 2017-09-15:

Task Name: email
Start time: 03:00
End time: 04:10
Description: Answer all the emails received today.

Task Name: email
Start time: 04:00
End time: 05:10
Description: Answer all the emails received today.
```

Ok so if you are interested and seeing your example data then this list are the things you want to learn:

datetime library:

- datetime.strptime() - string --> datetime
- datetime.strftime() - datetime --> string
- datetime.timedelta() - timedeltas

string formatting:

- str.format() - effective way to print strings
- ''.join() - effective way of converting list to strings

furthermore, to understand the code I wrote.. have a look at:

- json (a way to store information in human readable strings)
- dictionaries (store data in key,value pairs)
- pandas (pythons most effective library to deal with tabledata)
- sorted() function with the optional key parameter to sort data

I'm gonna give you some pieces if you want to continue:

```
array = [
    ['email', 9, 15, 2, 10, 70, 'Answer all the emails received today.'],
    ['email', 9, 15, 2, 0, 70, 'Answer all the emails received today.'],
    ['email', 9, 15, 3, 0, 70, 'Answer all the emails received today.']
]

printformat = """
Task Name: {}
Start time: {}
End time: {}
Description: {}
"""

date = [9,15]
s = ['These are your tasks for {}:\n'.format(date)]
for item in sorted(array,key=lambda x:(x[3],x[4])):
    if item[1:3] == date:
        s.append(printformat.format(item[0],item[1],item[2],item[3]))

print(''.join(s))
```

Returns:

```
These are your tasks for [9, 15]:

Task Name: email
Start time: 9
End time: 15
Description: 2

Task Name: email
Start time: 9
End time: 15
Description: 2

Task Name: email
Start time: 9
End time: 15
Description: 3
```

Comment: That sounds wonderful but since I am a beginner I don’t know how to use those libraries and am expected to use lists and nested variables. Thank you so much for the example though.

Comment: @hashicode no worries... and that's why I wrote you a list of items you should learn to be able to solve your specific problem. Learn those and you will think of this very differently.

Comment: I’ll definitely learn those. Could you help me think of it with lists and nested loops for now? If you have time. No worries if you can’t. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @hashicode Ofc I could but then I would be doing your homework. All information you need is in my example. Believe in yourself, it really isn't that hard... might look like it but learning the things I mentioned will save you lots of time. Also consider switching to `Python 3`. Good luck! :)

Comment: Ok, thank you :). Should I write a function that organizes the tasks by start time?

Comment: @hashicode I updated my answer with something you can start with. You still have to apply datetime library and figure out some formatting stuff. Basically you loop through the array that you sorted by hour and minutes (x[3], x[4]).

Comment: Thank you Anton! I will need a function that creates a list of dates from the tasks (what you call array), correct?
def make_date_from_tasks(tasks):
    dates = []
    for task in tasks:
        dates.append([task[1], task[2]])
    print(dates)
make_date_from_tasks(tasks)

Comment: @hashicode Why would you need that? I assume you are looking at the small last example and then if item[1:3] == date filters out dates

Comment: Hmm, I thought I would need that because the list of tasks is actually comprised of more tasks.

Comment: @hashicode Maybe you can share some larger data sample and show some sample code you are trying. It can be really time-consuming to "guess" further.

Comment: I added something called “Updated Code.” Right now, my program is printing all the tasks for all the days. How can I make it print the tasks for just one day?

Comment: @hashicode I added another answer where I use your updated code and made comments where you can change things.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing any other option than add a new answer:

```
import datetime

tasks = [
  ['email', 9, 15, 2, 0, 70, 'Answer all the emails received today.'],
  ['coffee', 10, 1, 8, 25, 5, 'making coffee'],
  ['meeting', 3, 5, 12, 0, 80, 'group meeting'],
  ['sleep', 12, 8, 3, 20, 280, 'getting some sleep'],
  ['meeting', 10, 1, 17, 0, 60, 'group meeting'],
  ['laundry', 3, 5, 21, 0, 40, 'do laundry'],
  ['office hours', 10, 1, 14, 0, 120, 'Office hours for Biology II'],
  ['class', 3, 5, 15, 0, 50, 'CS1 class'],
  ['laundry', 11, 5, 13, 0, 80, 'Laundry'],
  ['laundry', 10, 1, 19, 45, 40, 'Do laundry'],
  ['lunch', 10, 1, 12, 0, 30, 'Lunch time'],
  ['class', 3, 5, 10, 0, 50, 'Philosophy class'],
  ['break', 2, 1, 11, 0, 45, 'quick break before lunch.'],
  ['exam prep', 11, 13, 10, 0, 600, 'study for the exam.']]

printformat = """
Task Name: {}
Start time: {}
End time: {}
Description: {}
"""

def make_date_from_tasks(tasks):
    dates = []
    for task in tasks:
        dates.append([task[1], task[2]]) 
    dates = [list(item) for item in set(tuple(row) for row in dates)] # remove duplicates
    s_dates = sorted(dates) # sort
    return s_dates

def print_tasks(tasks, date):

    print("*"*40)

    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime('-'.join(str(i) for i in date),"%m-%d")
    dt_format = dt.strftime("%d %B")
    print('These are your tasks for {}:'.format(dt_format))

    for task in sorted(tasks, key =lambda x: (x[3],x[4])): #sort by hour and minutes
        if task[1:3] == date:
            name = task[0]
            duration = int(task[5])
            description = task[6]

            time = '-'.join(str(i) for i in task[3:5])
            stime = datetime.datetime.strptime(time,"%H-%M")
            etime = stime + datetime.timedelta(minutes=duration)

            print(printformat.format(name,
                                     stime.strftime("%I:%M %p"),
                                     etime.strftime("%I:%M %p"),
                                     description))

dates = make_date_from_tasks(tasks) # a list with all dates
for date in dates:
    print_tasks(tasks, date)
```

Returns:

```
****************************************
These are your tasks for 01 February:

Task Name: break
Start time: 11:00 AM
End time: 11:45 AM
Description: quick break before lunch.

****************************************
These are your tasks for 05 March:

Task Name: class
Start time: 10:00 AM
End time: 10:50 AM
Description: Philosophy class


Task Name: meeting
Start time: 12:00 PM
End time: 01:20 PM
Description: group meeting


Task Name: class
Start time: 03:00 PM
End time: 03:50 PM
Description: CS1 class


Task Name: laundry
Start time: 09:00 PM
End time: 09:40 PM
Description: do laundry

...
```

Comment: I'm watching a series atm. I can update this later :)

Comment: Can we do this without tuples? Ok, enjoy the show! :)